# PHP - Adding and Subtracting Days Weird Bug with DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I am trying to add and subtract # of days to a date using `date_add` and `date_sub`, but I get some weird results. I assume this is an easy answer I am just not versed enough in PHP to know why.

Here is my code:

```
$y = new DateTime('2016-05-17');
$z2 = 7;
$tempy = $y;
$tempy->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $z2 . 'D'));
$startdate = date_format($tempy, "Y-m-d");
$y->add(new DateInterval('P' . $z2 . 'D'));
$enddate = date_format($y, "Y-m-d");
echo "Start: " . $startdate . "  End: " . $enddate . "\r\n";
```

This is the result:

`Start: 2016-05-10  End: 2016-05-17`

It looks like even though I use a temporary variable `$tempy` for the start date it still modifies it and the end date is off.

EDIT:
Expected results:

`Start: 2016-05-10  End: 2016-05-24`

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: you should use DateTime::format() instead of mixing OO and procedural code (use of date_format)

Comment: See the edit that I made.

Comment: Also, use understandable variable names... it helps other to understand what you are actually trying to do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do :

```
$tempy = $y;
```

You create a pseudo reference to the first object, you don't actually copy it. To do so you need to use the `clone` keyword :

```
$tempy = clone $y;
```

Now things will work as you expect. Without cloning, when you modify `$tempy` it will also modify `$y`

EDIT : Adding link to manual about this (from @Devon's answer) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: This is perfect and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have only created one object (done with `new DateTime`), so all your operations on them (sub and add) are done on that one object regardless of how you reference it.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug, this is an expected result.  Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

```
$tempy = $y;
$tempy->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $z2 . 'D'));
```

At this point, both $tempy and $y have had 7 days subtracted because they point to the same instance.

```
$y->add(new DateInterval('P' . $z2 . 'D'));
```

Now both have had 7 days added back to it.  The only difference being when you export the formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake you were having is that you re-used your original `$date` with the assumption its state would not change. I've also refactored your code a little. In the time it's taken me to write this several answers have been posted, but I'll leave it if my example is easier to follow for some.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-05-17');

$calculateBeforeDate = clone $date;
$calculateAfterDate = clone $date;


$startDate = $calculateBeforeDate->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format('Y-m-d');

$endDate = $calculateAfterDate->add(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format('Y-m-d');

echo "Start: $startDate, End: $endDate" . PHP_EOL;
```

You'll notice on PHP.net docs that there are often interchangeable procedural style functions and object oriented ones. Try to utilise the OO ones whenever possible, so instead of using `date_format`, I used its OO equivalent.